# Тысячью и тысячей

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как объяснить разное написание (выбор Р.п. или Т.п.  для существительных) в счетных оборотах?

(1) С тысячью рублями/рублей  на катке делать нечего.

(2) Расходы исчисляются не одной тысячей рублей.

(3)  Стол завален тысячью безделушек.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Может быть, слово "тысячью" вообще не используется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форма тысяЧЬЮ - специфическая форма числительного, тысяЧЕЙ - форма существительного.

http://www.zerkalov.org/node/606

Академическая «Русская грамматика» 1980 года поясняет: Существительные, лексически обозначающие число или количество кого-чего-н., во всех падежах управляют существительным, называющим считаемые предметы: тысяча человек, тысячей (и тысячью) человек (и человеками), тысячей (и тысячью) рублей (и рублями); о тысяче человек; миллион книг, миллионом книг.

Слово тысяча управляет последующим существительным. Но откуда же в «Русской грамматике» формы тысячью человеками и тысячью рублями? Читаем дальше: В том случае, если в форме творительного падежа слово тысяча не имеет при себе определения, оно может, подобно числительному, согласовываться в падеже с зависящим от него существительным: с тысячью рублей и рублями (но только: с каждой тысячей рублей). Следовательно, согласование допускается только для формы творительного падежа тысячью (не тысячей!).

Таким образом, слово тысяча является существительным и во всех падежах управляет зависимым от него словом. При этом форма творительного падежа этого существительного – тысячей (с тысячей рублей).

Однако одновременно с формой творительного падежа существительного тысячей существует форма числительного – тысячью, в сочетании с которой согласование и управление конкурируют. Согласование возможно только в том случае, если слово тысяча обозначает точное число и не имеет при себе определения: с тысячью студентами, с тысячью знакомыми, с тысячью рублями в кармане.

Форма тысячью также может обозначать неопределенно большое количество чего-либо, в этом случае вместо согласования требуется управление: человек с тысячью лиц, в кабинете все заполнено тысячью бумаг; Воздух был наполнен тысячью разных птичьих свистов (Гоголь); тысячью буйных и огненных голов (Л. Андреев), тысячью мелких уколов (Короленко).

Правильно: тысяче работников, миллиону работников, трем тысячам работников (д. п.), тысячей работников, миллионом работников, тремя тысячами работников, тысячью работниками и одной тысячей работников (т. п.).

Правильно: обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам студентов, но обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам ста студентам.

По сути вопроса:

(1) С тысячью рублями/рублей на катке делать нечего.-устная разговорная речь, поэтому возможно и управление числительного существительным. Первая форма-норма письменной речи, вторая-разговорная.

(2) Расходы исчисляются не одной тысячей рублей.-есть определение ОДНОЙ, тысяча-существительное, управляет род. падежом.

(3) Стол завален тысячью безделушек.- Здесь слово ТЫСЯЧА означает "много", а не цифру 1000, значит, автор использовал разговорную форму творит. падежа существительного, а не числительное. Это Мамин-Сибиряк(пример классический, используемый во всех справочниках), своеобразный худ. приём, передача народной речи автором-рассказчиком.В худ. произведении это возможно. Если бы была письменно-книжная речь, нормой было бы "Стол завален ТЫСЯЧЕЙ безделушек", их же никто не считал.

Comment: Про последнее предложение. В чем разница-то? К кому? к студентам. Скольким? К двадцати пяти 
тысячам студентам.

Comment: Мне подобные пространные объяснения всегда казались недостаточными, поскольку никак не объясняют и даже не упоминают исторической формы согласования по типу числительного типа "кошелек с двумя тысячами рублями". Примеров у классиков - миллион.
//===  
Тут был [К. М.] фра<нцуз> женатый
На кукле чахлой и горбатой
И семи тысячах душах;
Тут был во всех своих звездах...
//===  
"Е.О." 8, XXVI.  

(Сперто с "Грамоты")

Comment: Лорана,"обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам студентов"- ПОСЛЕДНЕЕ слово "тысяча"воспринимается как существительное (как правило), поэтому управляет родит. падежом; "обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам ста студентам" - существительное СТУДЕНТАМ согласуется не с "тысячей", а со словом СТА(оно последнее), а это точно числительное. Мы знаем, что числительное управляет существительным в И.и В. падежах, а в остальных согласуется.

Comment: ДАВАЙТЕ ПОДВЕДЕМ ИТОГ.
1. У нас два значения:  точное число 1000 и  переносное значение «много, большое количество».
2. У нас три формы: Ф1: С ТЫСЯЧЕЙ РУБЛЕЙ (грамматическое сущ., управление Р.п.), Ф2: ТЫСЯЧЬЮ РУБЛЯМИ (грамматическое числительное, согласование в Т.п.) Ф3: ТЫСЯЧЬЮ  БЕЗДЕЛУШЕК (грамматическое сущ., управление Р.п.),
3.Выражаем ТОЧНОЕ ЧИСЛО: с тысячью рублями (с тысячей рублей – разговорный вариант, так как значение неточное).  Выражаем ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ: человек с тысячью лиц, стол завален тысячью безделушек.

Comment: 4. Форма  Ф4 «ТЫСЯЧЕЙ РУБЛЯМИ» вызывает сомнение. Сейчас он ненормативна, применялась ли раньше – надо искать примеры.

Answer (score 1):

> Как объяснить разное написание (выбор Р.п. или Т.п. для существительных) в счетных оборотах?

Тут по сути два вопроса, в отношении использования слова "тысяча" и в отношении падежа управляемого/зависимого слова.
См. у Людмилы, если осилите, хотя в отношении некоторых вещей можно и поспорить.

> (1) С тысячью рублями/рублей на катке делать нечего.

Можно и с "тысячей". Все четыре варианта ("с тысячей/тысячью рублей/рублями") в принципе возможны, но несут несколько разный смысл. Самый естественный вариант здесь - с тысячей рублей.

> (2) Расходы исчисляются не одной тысячей рублей.

Здесь тысячью невозможно, поскольку "тысяча" здесь не в составе числительного ("одна тысяча ровно"), а как самостоятельное существительное. При этом совершенно исключена форма "рублями", допустимая только при согласовании с числительным "тысячью".

> (3) Стол завален тысячью безделушек.

Аналогично (1). Все четыре варианта возможны, наиболее естественный - тысячей безделушек.

> Может быть, слово "тысячью" вообще не используется?

Используется, но только как числительное. 
В чем я не согласен с Людмилой (и её источником) - это в том, что при форме "тысячей" невозможно согласование. "Тысячей" и "тысячью" одинаково возможны в составе числительного (убедительных контраргументов не видел), значит и согласование возможно для обеих форм. Более того, до недавнего времени только оно, согласование, считалось нормативным. 
Иначе трудно объяснить примеры наподобие приведенного (из Пушкина) при полном отсутствии обратных из того времени.

Answer (score 0):

Путаница в восприятии 1000 рублей возникает в связи с тем, что каждому из нас всё равно, лежит у нас в кармане купюра, достоинством в 1000 рублей или 1000 монет по одному рублю. Но сумма и количество штук не одно и то же. Попробуйте заменить слово "рубль" на слово "червонец", и Вы получите однозначный ответ.